# Animating a parametric plot

Tags: plotting, animation, physics

I am attempting to animate my parametric plot, but am having difficulties. I tried simply wrapping the plot code with an `Animate[expression,{t,0,5}]`, but that hasn't worked, and I simply get a red animation screen. Any suggestions? Could someone tell me what is going wrong?

```
R= 2; l = 6; m = 9; g = -9.81; Subscript[t, 0] = 0; Subscript[t, f] = 1;

x[t_] = (l - R θ[t]) Cos[θ[t]] + R Sin[θ[t]];
y[t_] = R Cos[θ[t]] - (l - R θ[t]) Sin[θ[t]];

T = (1/2) m ((x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2);
U = m g (R Cos[θ[t]] - (l - R θ[t]) Sin[θ[t]]);
L = T - U;
EL[t_] = (D[L, θ[t]] - D[ D[L, θ'[t]], t]) // FullSimplify;

soln = NDSolve[{EL[t] == 0, θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 0}, θ, {t, Subscript[t, 0], Subscript[t, f]}]; 

ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[{(l - R θ[t]) Cos[θ[t]] + R Sin[θ[t]], R Cos[θ[t]] - (l - R θ[t]) Sin[θ[t]]} /. soln], {t, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> y, PlotRange -> {10}]
```

Comment: Animate with respect to *which variable*?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and forget using subscripted symbols until you master Mathematica really well

Comment: I am trying to animate with respect to t.

Comment: please do not use first UpperCase for variables, symbols and function names. If you must use single UpperCase letter, add a number to it. Say `R0` and `D0` and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that there are two errors in the `ParametricPlot`: (1) an error in the syntax of `PlotRange`, and (2) your time domain `{t,0,5}` goes outside the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction`. Be consistent with your choices of time domain by continuing to use $t_0$ and $t_f$, as shown below.

Second, as noted in the comments, avoid subscripts. I would use `t0` in place of `Subscript[t,0]`, although `t[0]` is another option.

Finally, note that because of the nature of the solution to the differential equation, $\theta(t)$ is oscillatory, and so the solution will trace out only a piece of the spiral you have plotted. I recommend plotting $\theta(t)$ directly to see this behavior.

Here is working code, with minimal changes that make it work, along with an animation where a point traces out the curve according to the solution of the differential equation.

```
r = 2; l = 6; m = 9; g = -9.81; t0 = 0; tf = 6.67;

x[t_] = (l - r θ[t]) Cos[θ[t]] + r Sin[θ[t]];
y[t_] = r Cos[θ[t]] - (l - r θ[t]) Sin[θ[t]];

kE = (1/2) m ((x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2);
pE = m g (r Cos[θ[t]] - (l - r θ[t]) Sin[θ[t]]);
lagrangian = kE - pE;
eL[t_] = (D[lagrangian, θ[t]] - D[D[lagrangian, θ'[t]], t]) //FullSimplify;

soln = NDSolve[{eL[t] == 0, θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 0}, θ, {t, t0, tf}];

Animate[ParametricPlot[{(l - r θ) Cos[θ] + r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ] - (l - r θ) Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, -20}, Epilog -> {PointSize -> 0.015, Evaluate[Point[{(l - r θ[t]) Cos[θ[t]] + r Sin[θ[t]],r Cos[θ[t]] - (l - r θ[t]) Sin[θ[t]]}] /. soln[[1]]]}], {t, t0, tf}]
```

Here is the result of the animation:

[image]